# library(printr) interact with data.table's ":=" when knit to html?

Tags: r, data.table, r-markdown, knitr

I have a markdown file which run in rstudio's console, but when i try to knit it into html it would take forever. Took me a long time of trial and error to nail down to what seems like including the "printr" library would trigger the := assignment of data.table to hang in kniting by trying to print out the whole table (very large in my case). Here is the code to demonstrate this. Is it a known "feature" of printr? It's worth pointing out that even the code block is `results='hide'` or `include=FALSE` and the table not shown in the html, the code would still run very slowly with printr included.

```
library(data.table)
library(bit64)
library(printr) # printr will make data.table := to print out the data in knit?
#test_n = 4000000 # with 4000000 and printr included it will take forever
test_n = 4000

print("slow chunk start:")
print(Sys.time())
DT = data.table(a = as.integer(1:test_n),
                b = as.integer64(1:test_n),
                c = as.integer(1:test_n))
DT[, seq:=1:.N] # whole table will print if printr is included
print(DT[1:10])
print("slow chunk end:")
print(Sys.time())
```

Comment: Assuming (1) you must use `printr`, and (2) `DT[, seq:=1:.N]` is the type of command where you don't want it to print at all but it is, then perhaps `invisible(DT[, seq:=1:.N])`? That should preclude attempting to print it to the console. (Another technique would be to assign the result to an otherwise-unused variable, such as `ign <- DT[, seq:=1:.N]`, which should also prevent automatic printing.)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the `data.table` package defines a `print` method for data.tables, but doesn't define a `knit_print` method, so `knitr` uses the `knit_print.data.frame` method that was defined in `printr`, and it prints the whole thing.

There are a couple of simple solutions.  @r2evans suggested using `invisible()`, e.g. `invisible(DT[, seq:=1:.N])`.  This will work, because `knitr` won't try to print things if you ask it not to.

Another simple solution is to provide your own `knit_print` method that doesn't print anything, e.g.

```
knit_print.data.table <- function(x, ...) NULL
```

Put this early in your document and you will never have data.tables printing.  If you sometimes want them to print, you could set an option, e.g.

```
knit_print.data.table <- function(x, ...) {
  if (getOption("print.data.tables", FALSE)) # default to FALSE
    NextMethod()
}
```

This will by default not print, but if you want it to print, run

```
options(print.data.tables = TRUE)
```

beforehand (and set it to FALSE afterwards if you only want it to happen once).

Yet another somewhat undocumented approach is to set the method as

```
knit_print.data.table <- function(x, ...) {
  if (data.table::shouldPrint(x)) 
    NextMethod()
}
```

The docs for `shouldPrint` suggest this is the right solution, but they do warn against using it.

Comment: thanks this makes sense. i think i will try not to use printr, if i have to, i'd default the `knit_print.data.table` like you suggested.
so `data.table's print` default to do nothing is that why when run in console the assignment wouldn't print?

Comment: No, in a console `data.table` does some weird stuff to avoid printing, an internal version of `shouldPrint()`.  I don't know why they don't just mark the object invisible, which would also work fine with `knitr`.

Comment: Whenever return is invisible then object was changed by reference

Comment: In users console it does, in knitr I believe it does as well. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/6c1fd839e0e0257d13f07975ead0fe6fdfee2f61/tests/knitr.Rout.save#L44 I don't know what is printr and how it interfere into DT and knitr.

Comment: I didn't say anything about use of `withVisible` @user2554330